# How do you write an HREF link to a specific controller and action in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a small application. I have written some of the code in `index.ctp` file and this file is working fine. Now I have added another function called `add` to my Controller file and also created a seperate file called `add.ctp` in `Views` folder.

My doubt is how to navigate to add.ctp file if I click a link. I want to create a menu in my main file and write a link so that when I click on that link the page must navigate to add() function.

My problem is:

1. How to write href in cake php?
2. What link do I provide? Controller or Views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) would be a good place to start your CakePHP journey. Then you'd quickly notice it's very easy to link to a controller action from your views with:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Link text', array(
    'controller' => 'controller_name',
    'action' => 'add'
));
```

Comment: One more doubt where exactly i need to write this code? In my controller file? And how to call it later on??

Comment: No, this goes in your View or Layout, on the place where you want the link to appear.

Comment: A little confusion here. I've so far used controller names in helper like this 'controller'=>'PostCategories' but here you are saying to use it like 'controller'=>'post_categories'. Does it make any difference because I have just started receiving an error where these two words are concatenated with an underscore rather than hyphen. It is causing error now. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

You can create hyperlink in view like this:

```
echo $this->link('text',
    array('controller'=>'controllerName','action'=>'actionName'));
```

you are able to create URLs just from controllerName and it's action:

```
echo $this->Html->url(
    array('controller' => 'controllerName','action' =>'actionName'),true);?>
```